# Symfony Doctrine field type conversion DC2Type:array -> DC2Type:json

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Just recently changed annotation for column that holds an array:

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="array")
*/
```

To this one

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="json")
*/
```

And got the migration diff from doctrine:

```
'ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE mycolumn mycolumn LONGTEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:json)\''
```

In case I have data stored already in that field as a serialized array, will I have any issues with deserializing them after migration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an exception will be raised with code "3140" inform you that invalid value already exist, I advise you to create a custum script with any language to convert all values stored in your DB, I have already often face this problem and I created a convertion PHP script using regular expression. but I no still have the script unfortunately :(